# In Python, how to print a value from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print out a certain value from a list. Here is my code:

```
rdf_f = open("substrate.txt")
for line in rdf_f:
    fields = line.split()
    if len(fields) > 1:
        x = fields[1]
    print(x[2])
```

How can I correctly use the `print()` command to print out the 3rd value of `x`? Because I got an error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I know if `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`, my code works. But here `x` is a perpendicular column. When I use `print(x)`, the output is

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
...
```

Comment: If you replace `print(x[2])` with `print(x)`, what do you get?

Comment: Your `x` is a string and not a list! Because you assign the second string of the list `fileds` to it.

Comment: @thegrinner A column that I described in the question

Comment: You are only assigning x a single value (the second one in your list you recieve by the line.split() function). BTW: You're code will also fail, when - for example - len(fields) <= 1 on the first call, because you want to print x which has never been assigned a value.

Comment: @TobiMarg You're right. But how can I print the 3rd value of this string. The format is different from the normal string.

Comment: That column isn't a list, it's a string (hence the error). You need to convert it to a list before you can access it like a list.

Comment: @thegrinner that is not correct strings can be accessed in that way, but the string is in that case shorter than 3 characters.

Comment: @cyphorious No! my x is a string here and has the value that I showed in the question. But this string is in a perpendicular format

Comment: Could you post the full content of `x` (`print(x)`) right before the error occurs?

Comment: @TobiMarg You're right, I phrased that *very* poorly. What I was trying to say was `x` represented in the final code block obviously isn't a single string because of the index being out of range, and that putting all those values into a list would let OP access it like he wanted. I brain farted the last half of my comment pretty bad :(

Answer (score 5):

You got that error because there are no items at that index.
So you better use for loop. And print all items.

```
for item in fields:
    print item
```

OR

Check for the length of fields list and print accordingly.

```
   if len(fields)>3:
      print fields[3]
```

Comment: +1. It is often the problem when a text file is read. It often happens that the last line of a text file is the empty line that is not visible in editor by naked eye.

Answer (score 1):

Your list is fields, not x. Perhaps the value you are looking for is fields[2]